# How to get windows tasks and background tasks seperatly in a list?

Tags: python, operating-system, subprocess, task

i'm trying to make a quick shortcut to end all active tasks except windows tasks and i need to get a list of active tasks, i searched a bit and found a an answer but i have problem at reading and using the output and i should seperate windows tasks.

this is the answer i found.

```py
import subprocess
t=subprocess.check_output(['tasklist'])
```

i wanted to have a list like this:

```py
["chrome.exe","sedsvc.exe",....]
```

but that command gives me a bytes object like this:

```py
b"Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage

========================= ======== ================ =========== ============

System Idle Process              0 Services                   0          8 K

System                           4 Services                   0    122,932 K

smss.exe                       292 Services                   0        740 K"
```

is there any other way to get them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the tasklist e.g.

```
import re
import subprocess

tasks = subprocess.check_output(['tasklist']).decode('cp866', 'ignore').split("\r\n")
p = []
for task in tasks:
    m = re.match(b'(.*?)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(.*?)\\s.*', task.encode())
    if m is not None:
        p.append(m.group(1).decode())
print(p)
```

`p` will hold the list as you wanted e.g. `["chrome.exe","sedsvc.exe",....]`, but you will need to strip system processes.